# Using Biopython to retrieve details on an unknown sequence by BLAST

Tags: python, biopython, blast, ncbi

I'm using Biopython for the first time. I have sequence data from unknown organisms, and trying to use BLAST to tell which organism they are most likely to have come from. I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def find_organism(file):
    """
    Receives a fasta file with a single seq, and uses BLAST to find
    from which organism it was taken.
    """
    # get seq from fasta file
    seqRecord = SeqIO.read(file,"fasta")
    # run BLAST
    blastResult = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seqRecord.seq)
    # get first hit
    blastRecord = NCBIXML.read(blastResult)
    firstHit = blastRecord.alignments[0]
    # get hit's gi number
    title = firstHit.title
    gi = title.split("|")[1]
    # search NCBI for the gi number
    ncbiResult = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=gi, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
    ncbiResultSeqRec = SeqIO.read(ncbiResult,"gb")
    # get organism
    annotatDict = ncbiResultSeqRec.annotations
    return(annotatDict['organism'])
```

It works fine, but takes about 2 minutes to retrieve the organism for each species, which seems very slow to me. I'm just wondering if I could do better. I know that I may create a local copy of NCBI to improve performance, and I might do that. However, I suspect that querying BLAST first, then take the id and use it to query Entrez is not the way to go. Do you have any other suggestions for improvements?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the organism with:

```
[...]
blastResult = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seqRecord.seq)
blastRecord = NCBIXML.read(blastResult)

first_organism = blastRecord.descriptions[0]
```

This would save at least the efetch query. Anyway the "blastn" can take too long, and if you are planning to massively query the NCBI you're going to be banned.

Comment: Doesn't work. This simply returns the whole sequence header, not the organism. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Isn't the organism in the description? In my tests there was! I guess it depends on the query. Can you supply a sample sequence to do the queries?

Comment: I'm querying on this sequence:  NNNNttaNNcaATATGAANCGGGTTGGGACCTCACCTCGGTGAGGGCTCCAGCTTGTCTGAATTATTCACCCATGTCTTT
TGCGCACTTCTTGTTTCCTGGGCGGGTTCGCCCGCCACCAGGACCAAACCATAAACCTTTTTGTAATTGCAATCAGCGTC
AGTAAACAATGTAATTATTACAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGC

Comment: I'm playing around, and it seems that the qblast service is being slowed at the NCBI. The same query that takes 5 seconds using the web interface takes like 5-10 minutes using the qblast API (without Biopython, just using the Put command as recommended). If your main concern is the speed, it seems that you can either a) do it locally or b) hack the web form.